# Using <nav> <ul> and <li> to make navbar instead of a table. How do I make whole block clickable while spanning the width of the page?

Tags: html, css, html-lists, nav

There are three goals I have with this nav bar.

- To make it 140px tall to fit a logo. This block will have a fixed width.
- To make each link block have an even width and have the nav bar span the page.
- To make the entire block clickable to the link.

Here is my code:

```css
nav {
  position: absolute;
  list-style-type: none;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  height: 140px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  overflow: hidden;
}
li {
  width: 16.7%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-family: 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="homepage" title="Home Page">
        <img src="r3wmod.png">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="about" title="About Me">ABOUT</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="projects" title="Projects">PROJECTS</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="thoughts" title="Thoughts">THOUGHTS</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="resume" title="Resume">RESUME</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: With this code, the nav bar doesn't span the width of the page and the blocks aren't clickable. How can I make it so they are clickable and span the width of the page?

Comment: I suggest you to update your post with the question, not sure that everyone read also the comments

Comment: Yeah the title is a little confusing